# Displaylink installation problem dependecies with libc6 and kernel 5.18

Tags: 20.04, displaylink

I fell into a rabbit-hole and I am even not sure where I lost the track.

The issue started today morning when I connected my docking station via USB-C to my Dell Latitude 5491 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. There are 2 additional screens which I was using  without any problems. In fact, there was an issue that my PC didn't recognize the screens when they are connected to via docking when I first installed the screens (a year ago) and I found out about [DisplayLink](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics) and everything worked flawless after installing the displaylink drivers - until today.

Intuitively, I did `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt autoclean` etc. but no screen detected.

Then I tried to reinstall displaylink drivers with `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.6.0-59.176.run` . The return is:

```
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.6.0-59.176  100%  
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Unsatisfied dependencies. Missing component: Linux headers for running kernel, 5.18.6-051806-generic.
This is a fatal error, cannot install DisplayLink Linux Software.
gizem@gizem-ubuntu2004:~/Downloads/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software
```

I then tried to downgrade the linux kernel to 5.15 but there are some dependency errors as you see here:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.9.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
```

When I try installing `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic` then I get a message saying that:

```
linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
```

The `apt --fix-broken install` does not solved anything because the requirement says that I need **libc6 (>= 2.34)**. I cannot install higher than 2.31 because it says to me that libc6 is already at the newest version.

I am even not sure if it is a kernel issue but I would like to explain all the steps so that maybe someone can suggest something which I haven't tried. Very much appreciated for all kinds of help!

Comment: As you have discovered, there are some dependency issues between Ubuntu version 20.04 and more recent kernels. You appear to have installed some non-standard, perhaps mainline, kernels. For Ubuntu 20.04 without HWE you should be using kernel 5.4.0-121-generic, and with HWE kernel 5.13.0-51-generic.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I downgraded the kernel to 5.13.0.51-generic and it solved the problem.